# Html.DropDownList - Disabled/Readonly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What option do I need to set to make a drop down box readonly when using MVCs Html.DropDownList?

I've tried things like....

```
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { _Enabled = "false" })
```

...and many different things along this line; alas no joy!

I thought this would be an easy.....and it probably is!

Comment: Notice @Thomas' answer below. Marking the Html.DropDownList as disabled stops the form from posting the value it holds. How can the control be disabled or read-only but still submit the form value on post?

Comment: how to Dynamic setting attribute disabled with one bool value?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Try this

```
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: But by doing this the bind value of drop down list wont get at the controller.

Comment: trying to use this but its not working no matter the variation

 @Html.DropDownList("Tug_ID", model => model.Tug_ID, new { @disabled = "disabled" })

Comment: but this will prevent the DDL value to be submitted with form.

Comment: add hidden field for DropdownList  if you want to get the value at the controller.

Comment: this won't pass the value to controller and read-only will not freeze the drop-down so the best way is to use disable and a hidden field which will store value and then will pass it to controller.

Comment: @Jamie R， how to Dynamic setting attribute disabled with one bool value?

Comment: @Superman not sure what you are referring to. Can I suggest to open a new question

Comment: @JamieR, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275015/how-to-dynamic-setting-html-dropdownlist-attribute-disabled-in-razorview

Comment: @VishnuVikraman, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351554/get-value-of-disabled-drop-down-in-asp-net-mvc) might be the perfect answer for you,

Comment: Is it just me or does `new { @disabled = "anyword" }` cause the controller in question to be disabled?

Answer (score 104):

Regarding the catch 22:

If we use `@disabled`, the field is not sent to the action (Mamoud)
And if we use `@readonly`, the drop down bug still lets you change the value

Workaround: use `@disabled`, and add the field hidden after the drop down:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.xxxxxxxx)
```

Then it is truly disabled, and sent to the to the action too.

Comment: That is the most useful solution I've found. I don't know why it got so little votes.

Comment: Really good tip. I only followed the answer without looking at the comment below it, and it took me 2 hours to find out why a zero value is being set in the post back

Comment: You have to be careful with this solution: MVC will print two elements with attribute `id="MyModelField"`, which can be tricky if you're willing to interact with the select/hidden elements using JS.

Comment: But this is not valid html. You'll have two elements with the same ID

Comment: To work around the issue raised by @CătălinRădoi, just create the hidden using a custom ID using `new {id = "SomeId"}`

Comment: Another problem with this is unobtrusive validation won't get triggered on disabled controls. However the correct values will be posted. Seems like it't only so much you can do.

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $(document) .ajaxStart(function () {
                $("#dropdownID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $("#dropdownID").removeAttr("disabled");

            });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This one didn't work for me, could you expand the example.

Answer (score 3):

I had to disable the dropdownlist and hide the primary ID

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OBJ_ID, "Objs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("OBJ_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OBJ_ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OBJ_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

A tip that may be obvious to some but not others..

If you're using the HTML Helper based on `DropDownListFor` then your ID will be duplicated in the `HiddenFor` input. Therefore, you'll have duplicate IDs which is invalid in HTML and if you're using javascript to populate the `HiddenFor` and `DropDownList` then you'll have a problem.

The solution is to manually set the ID property in the htmlattributes array...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Entity)

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
  model => model.Entity, 
  new { 
         @class = "form-control sharp", 
         onchange = "", 
         id =` "EntityDD", 
         disabled = "disabled" 
       }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try something like this:

```
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { @readonly = "true" })
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The drop-down is grayed out, but still enabled and usable.

Comment: Hi, I want to disable/enable the dropdown for specific pages only based on the value,i am passing it through model. i tried passing true / false to the disabled but it's not working .can you help in this

Answer (score 2):

Put this in style

```
 select[readonly] option, select[readonly] optgroup {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just do this and call it a day

```
Model.Id > -1 ? Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Property, new { disabled = "disabled" }) : Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Property)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { @disabled = "" })
```

Works

Answer (score 0):

Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.Hidden(Model.Types)
and for save and recover the data, use a hidden control

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the HTML Helper for DropDownListFor that adds enabled parameter, when false select is disabled. It keeps html attributes defined in markup, or it enables usage of html attributes in markup, it posts select value to server and usage is very clean and simple.

Here is the code for helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes, bool enabled)
{
  if (enabled)
  {
    return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(html, expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
  }

  var htmlAttributesAsDict = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  htmlAttributesAsDict.Add("disabled", "disabled");
  string selectClientId = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
  htmlAttributesAsDict.Add("id", selectClientId + "_disabled");

  var hiddenFieldMarkup = html.HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(expression);
  var selectMarkup = SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(html, expression, selectList, htmlAttributesAsDict);
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectMarkup.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + hiddenFieldMarkup.ToString());
}
```

and usage, goal is to disable select if there is just one item in options, markup:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeValue, Model.SomeList, new { @class = "some-class" }, Model.SomeList > 1)
```

And there is one even more elegant HTML Helper example, no post support for now (pretty straight forward job, just use HAP and add hidden input as root element sibling and swap id's):

```
public static MvcHtmlString Disable(this MvcHtmlString previous, bool disabled, bool disableChildren = false)
{
  if (disabled)
  {
    var canBeDisabled = new HashSet<string> { "button", "command", "fieldset", "input", "keygen", "optgroup", "option", "select", "textarea" };
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(previous.ToString());
    var rootElements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
      hn => hn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && 
      canBeDisabled.Contains(hn.Name.ToLower()) && 
      (disableChildren || hn.ParentNode.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Document));

    foreach (var element in rootElements)
    {
      element.SetAttributeValue("disabled", "");
    }
    string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
  }
  return previous;
}
```

For example there is a model property bool AllInputsDisabled, when true all html inputs should be disabled:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { placeholder = "Enter address" }).Disable(Model.AllInputsDisabled)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DoYou, Model.YesNoList).Disable(Model.AllInputsDisabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach

Disabling all the options except the selected one:

```
<select>
    <option disabled>1</option>
    <option disabled>2</option>
    <option selected>3</option>
</select>
```

This way the dropdown still submits, but the user can not select another value.

With jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#yourSelectId option:not(:selected)').prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The OP was specifically asking about the use of Html.DropDownList in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

try with @disabled and jquery, in that way you can get the value on the Controller.

```
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new {@class = "your_class disabled", @disabled= "disabled" })
```

Add a class called "disabled" so you can enabled by searching that class(in case of multiples disabled fields), then you can use a "setTimeout" in case of not entering controller by validation attributes

```
<script>

  function clickSubmit() {
    $("select.disabled").attr("disabled", false);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("select.disabled").attr("disabled", true);
    }, 500);
  }
</script>
```

submit button like this.

```
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="clickSubmit();">Save</button>
```

in case of inputs, just use @readonly="readonly"

```
@Html.TextBoxFor("Types",Model.Types, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly= "readonly" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the select as readonly and then run some jquery to disable the options except the selected value. You cant change the value and it's included when the form is submitted.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#readonlyTest').find('select[readonly] option').not('select[readonly] option[selected]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
  $('#formData').html(formData);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="scopeReadonlyNoJs">Scope Readonly No Js</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="scopeReadonlyNoJs" name="scopeReadonlyNoJs" readonly="readonly">
      <option value="">Select..</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="readonlyNoJsScopeValue1">Scope Value 1</option>
      <option value="readonlyNoJsScopeValue2">Scope Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <small id="scopeReadonlyNoJsHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is read only and no js is applied. It looks disabled but you can change the values.</small>
  </div>
  <div id="readonlyTest" class="form-group">
    <label for="scopeReadonly">Scope Readonly</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="scopeReadonly" name="scopeReadonly" readonly="readonly">
      <option value="">Select..</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="readonlyScopeValue1">Scope Value 1</option>
      <option value="readonlyScopeValue2">Scope Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <small id="scopeReadonlyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is read only and is disabled via js by disabling the options except the selected one.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="scopeDisabled">Scope Disabled</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="scopeDisabled" name="scopeDisabled" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="">Select..</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="disabledScopeValue1">Scope Value 1</option>
      <option value="disabledScopeValue2">Scope Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <small id="scopeDisabledHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is disabled and wont be posted.</small>
  </div>
  <button id="submitButton" type="button">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
<p id="formData">
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've create this answer after referring above all comments & answers.
This will resolve the dropdown population error even it get disabled.

**Step 01**

```html
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new {@readonly="readonly"})
```

**Step 02** 
This is css pointerevent remove code.

```css
<style type="text/css">
    #Types {
        pointer-events:none;
    }
</style>
```

Then you can have expected results

Tested & Proven