# Making a drop down list readonly but still submitting its value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am using the Html.DropDownList helper in ASP.NET MVC and I would like to make it read-only.  Unfortunately, I also need it to submit its value on a form post.

I have found (through a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636103)) that using the below format will make the drop down read-only but it will not provide access to the control's value within the controller.

```
Html.DropDownList("Types", Model.Types, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Does anyone know how to make a drop down list read-only or disabled with ASP.NET MVC while also allowing it to submit with a form post?

Comment: It's really weird: We've been using the code you include in your question, and it has worked just fine for us until this week. I suspect either the update to MVC 3 or the Client-side Validation features that we added recently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's intended behavior on the web browser side - a disabled control will not post it's data to the server when a form is submitted.

You can fake it by putting a hidden field on the page with the value in it - just be sure to validate the data. Or use javascript to enable the field before the submit action happens.

If you're disabling a field, but still showing it on the page with some value, then there must be a way for you to know that value without having it send back from the browser to the server.

Answer (score 10):

You can enable it on submit. Downside: it looks weird.

```
$(form).submit(function() {
  $('#Types').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

or copy the value into a hidden field on submit.

```
$(form).submit(function() {
  $('#HiddenField').val($('#Types').val());
});
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Make it a textbox instead.
2. Add a change event with JavaScript:

   `$('#dropdown').change(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`
3. Have a dropdown list with only 1 item in it.
4. Have a hidden item with the actual value of the dropdown in it, so that gets submitted even if the disabled dropdown doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just alter the stylesheet of that item.

```
visibility:"visible"
visibility:"hidden"
```

For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199243.

You will still get the postback but you also won't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution is to post it via

```
$.post(url,
{
   AID: val1,
   CID: val2
},
  function (data) {
    // act on model
  }
);
```