# How to create a readonly textbox in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, readonly-attribute

How do I create a readonly textbox in ASP.NET MVC3 with the Razor view engine?

Is there an HTMLHelper method available to do that?

Something like the following?

```
@Html.ReadOnlyTextBoxFor(m => m.userCode)
```

Answer (score 266, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userCode, new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

You are welcome to make an HTML Helper for this, but this is simply just an HTML attribute like any other.  Would you make an HTML Helper for a text box that has other attributes?

Comment: @Shyju Sorry, I was missing the `@` prefix of the `readonly` property.  See my edit.

Comment: In the future, if you get any kind of errors adding properties to the dynamic object argument you can prefix them with the `@`. You'll usually only see it with keywords that match HTML attributes (like readonly, class, etc.)

Comment: @BradChristie: No; you only need an `@` to use attributes that match **C#** keywords.

Comment: @SLaks: Isn't that what I said? ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie: I misread your comment ("keywords" was ambiguous)

Comment: If you have multiple html attributes you can do something like: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userCode, new { @readonly="readonly", @class="form-control" })`

Answer (score 36):

**UPDATE:**
Now it's very simple to add HTML attributes to the default editor templates. It neans instead of doing this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userCode, new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

you simply can do this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.userCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly="readonly" } })
```

Benefits: You haven't to call `.TextBoxFor`, etc. for templates. Just call `.EditorFor`.

---

While @Shark's solution works correctly, and it is simple and useful, my solution (that I use always) is this one: **Create an `editor-template` that can handles `readonly` attribute**:

1. Create a folder named `EditorTemplates` in `~/Views/Shared/`
2. Create a razor `PartialView` named `String.cshtml`
3. Fill the `String.cshtml` with this code:

   ```
   @if(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly) {
       @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
           new { @class = "text-box single-line readonly", @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled" })
   } else {
       @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
           new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
   }
   ```
4. In model class, put the `[ReadOnly(true)]` attribute on properties which you want to be `readonly`.

For example,

```
public class Model {
    // [your-annotations-here]
    public string EditablePropertyExample { get; set; }

    // [your-annotations-here]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string ReadOnlyPropertyExample { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use Razor's default syntax simply:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EditablePropertyExample)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReadOnlyPropertyExample)
```

The first one renders a normal `text-box` like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="field-id" name="field-name" />
```

And the second will render to;

```
<input readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" class="text-box single-line readonly" id="field-id" name="field-name" />
```

You can use this solution for any type of data (`DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `DataType.Text`, `DataType.MultilineText` and so on). Just create an `editor-template`.

Comment: +1 because you used "ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsReadOnly". I was expecting MVC would take into account these stuff in version 4.

Comment: @cleftheris well we are in version 5 now, and MVC still didn't take them ;)

Comment: @Javad_Amiry - great answer - I've implemented it and it seemed to work great until I clicked Save on a Scaffolded Edit page. Then it turns out Properties with [ReadOnly(true)] will result in NULL being sent to the database instead of the real Property value - Have you come across this?

Answer (score 5):

The solution with TextBoxFor is OK, but if you **don't want to see the field like EditBox stylish** (it might be a little confusing for the user) involve changes as follows:

1. Razor code before changes

   ```
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
   </div>
   ```
2. After changes

   ```
   <!-- New div display-field (after div editor-label) -->
   <div class="display-field">
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Text)
   </div>

   <div class="editor-field">
       <!-- change to HiddenFor in existing div editor-field -->
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Text)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
   </div>
   ```

Generally, this solution prevents field from editing, but shows value of it.
There is no need for code-behind modifications.

Comment: I think that having the CSS for the classes editor-field and display-field here might be really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by *"this solution disables filed against editing,"* (it seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13587678/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).

Answer (score 4):

With credits to the previous answer by @Bronek and @Shimmy:

This is like I have done the same thing in ASP.NET Core:

```
<input asp-for="DisabledField" disabled="disabled" />
<input asp-for="DisabledField" class="hidden" />
```

The first input is readonly and the second one passes the value to the controller and is hidden. I hope it will be useful for someone working with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.TextBox("Receivers", Model, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 300px", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { readonly= "readonly" })
```

This is just fine for text box. However, if you try to do same for the `checkbox` then try using this if you are using it:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { onclick = "return false" })
```

But don't use `disable`, because disable always sends the default value `false` to the server - either it was in the checked or unchecked state. And the `readonly` does not work for checkbox and `radio button`. `readonly` only works for `text` fields.

Comment: What about drop down lists?

Comment: Hope this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636103/html-dropdownlist-disabled-readonly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for creating a TextBox as read-only.

**Method 1**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fields[i].TheField, new { @readonly = true })
```

**Method 2**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fields[i].TheField, new { htmlAttributes = new {disabled = "disabled"}})
```