# MVC 4 Checkbox/radiobutton readonly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

can anyone tell me how can I make a checkbox readonly instead of disabled?
For a textbox, I am using it like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { id = "fName", @readonly="readonly" })
```

Now, I have a checkbox and a radiobutton like this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Iseighteen, new { id = "18", @disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isMale, new { id = "male",@disabled = "disabled" })
```

The problem with the disabled is that I can't get focus in the disabled field while I can get a focus in the read only. If I tab then it selects the readonly fields so that the screen reader can read it but if its disabled then it skips everything disabled and goes to the footer. I tried using readonly for checkbox and radio but it doesn't work and lets the user edit.
So, any suggestions on that?

Comment: I would think that your read only attempt should work according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761647/how-to-create-readonly-textbox-in-asp-net-mvc3-razor good luck.

Comment: Radio buttons can't be ReadOnly ...This post help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953017/why-cant-radio-buttons-be-readonly

Answer (score 5):

You can user the below Code to restrict users from selecting Checkbox and radiobutton ...

```
  $(':radio,:checkbox').click(function(){
return false;
   });
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { onclick = "return false" })
```

Hope it will work more easy way.