# Enable/Disable a 'DropDownListFor' on a checkbox selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working show the drop down values on selection of a check box. But with the below code, all different items that are present in the drop down coming directly.

Somehow the @Html.DropDownListFor is not working inside select tag, can anyone please help me to fix it?

Note: Checkbox toggle working perfectly.

Thank you,

### .cshtml

```
<input type="checkbox" /> 
<p>check this box to escalate</p>          
<select disabled="disabled">    
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.EscalationQueue,
        new SelectList(Extensions.EscalationQueue, Model.EscalationQueue),
          new { @class = "escalation-queue", name = Model.EscalationQueue }
)  
</select>
```

### .js file

```
var dropdownToggle = function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if ($("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    dropdownToggle();
});
```

Output:

[image: CurrentOutput1]

[image: CurrentOutput2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need the `<select>` tag, the `HtmlHelper`  `DropDownListFor` will render that for you.
If you want to initialize the dropdown as disabled set the html attribute as you did for declaring a cssclass...

```
<input type="checkbox" /> 
<p>check this box to escalate</p>  
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.EscalationQueue,
        new SelectList(Extensions.EscalationQueue, Model.EscalationQueue),
        new { @class = "escalation-queue", 
                name = Model.EscalationQueue, 
                disabled= "disabled" 
         }
)
```

Comment: Suppose i need to disable the DropDownList instead of DropDownListFor means where i have to give the  disabled= "disabled"

Comment: Hi, I want to disable/enable the dropdown for specific pages only based on the value,i am passing it through model. i tried passing true / false to the disabled but it's not working .can you help in this

Comment: @JasperManickaraj, For that, please visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636103/html-dropdownlist-disabled-readonly)