# Get value of disabled drop down in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, post, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I am having multiple drop-down list in my page (HTML SELECT), I have to disable them, as user goes on selected them one by one. When the user posts it back to the controller, I am getting null as the function (action method) paramters. I searched and found that HTML does not send value of disabled fields in the form data. Replacing disabled attribute with readonly would not work as it would render drop-down working.

I am generating the dropdowns dynamically using javascript as user goes on. So there isn't a single dropdown, but as many as user wants.

Can someone please tell me how should I get the values ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

One possibility is to make the dropdown list `disabled="disabled"` and include a hidden field with the same name and value which will allow to send this value to the server:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FooId, Model.Foos, new { disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FooId)
```

If you have to disabled the dropdown dynamically with javascript then simply assign the currently selected value of the dropdown to the hidden field just after disabling it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of disabled controls. I suggest you to add a hidden field and set the value of your DropDownList in this hidden field and work with this.

Something like:

```
//just to create a interface for the user
@Html.DropDownList("categoryDump", (SeectList)ViewBag.Categories, new { disabled = "disabled" });
// it will be send to the post action
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryID)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also create your own DropDownListFor overload which accepts a `bool disabled` parameter and does the heavy lifting for you so your view isn't cluttered with `if disablethisfield then ...`.

Something among these lines could do:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool disabled)
{
    if (disabled)
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression).ToString() + htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, new { disabled="disabled" }).ToString());
    else
        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList);
}
```

There are 6 overloads for DropDownListFor alone so it's a lot of monkeycoding but it pays off in the end imho.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field with a specified Id and set it before disabling the drop-down-list.

> In MVC,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FooId, Model.Foos)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FooId, new { @id = "hdnFooId" })
```

> In JQuery,

```
function handleDropDownListFooChange(){
    // Get the selected value from drop-down-list before disabling it.
    var selectedFooId = $('#FooId').val();
    $('#FooId').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#hdnFooId").val(selectedFooId);

    // Load any data the depends on selected FooId using `selectedFooId` variable.
}
```

The selected value will automatically be binded to `Model.FooId`.

Answer (score -1):

before submit call $('#FooId').removeAttr('disabled')

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is getting down voted? If you down vote, give a reason please.

Comment: I think because if you use this solutions in a slow environment, the user will see that the dropdown is enabled. Also, the user can now edit the value inside and re-submit the form.