# How to get disabled DropDownList control value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Work on asp.net mvc5.My project DropDownList work perfectly problem arise when i disabled **DropDownList** control then can not get value in **controller.**

**My razor syntax is bellow:**

```
 <div class="form-group">

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductName, new {@class = "col-md-3 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ProductID", null, "Select product", new {@placeholder = "Select product", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**my controller syntax to fill the above DropDownList**

```
 private void LoadProductsInViewData(object selectedValue = null)
        {
            var datas = productRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(datas, "ProductID", "Name", selectedValue);
        }
```

Why In controller create/edit event can not get the DropDownList value?
Note:I know it's disabled control default behavior,i try to use hidden column like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636103/html-dropdownlist-disabled-readonly).Problem is how hidden column used with my approach.

Comment: Disabled form controls do not post back a value - do not disable it. But what is the point using a dropdownlist if you do not want to select something Just put the value in a hidden input

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thanks for your reply,I need to use dropdownList.In my  model there is no property named ProductID and there is no list for dropdownlist.Hope you understand

Comment: A dropdownlist for what? - you cant select anything so what is the point. Hard to understand what you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to retrive the value of Currently Selected item of DropList which is disabled in your case, using

```
       var dropDownValue=("#Id_of_u_Dropdownlist").val()
```

and you can send the DropDownValue variable which contains value of Disable Dropdown list to Controller.

Comment: Gaurav Divate thanks for your reply, my submit button work under @using (Html.BeginForm()) {} so how i send javascript value in controller,Please don't day used ajax approach

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior. Disabled fields cannot be posted, then it's a common pratice to add a `Html.HiddenFor()` to post the disabled value.

As you said, there is no `"ProductId"` property in your model. However, if you create a `Html.Hidden("ProductId", "YourValue")` and add a parameter named 'productId' in your Controller Create/Edit action, the value should be subimitted.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Httpost Action and then use FormCollection Object like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDropDownValue(FormCollection Form)
    {
        string dropdownValue=form["ID_of_dropdownlist"].toString();
    }
```