# how to Dynamic setting Html.DropDownList attribute disabled in RazorView?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Here it is my Drop-down:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OptionType", selectList, new { @class = "form-control", name = "OptionType",@disabled = "disabled" })
```

The above code can set DropDownList is disabled，but I want to dynamic set disabled attribute with a bool value from model. In other words if bool value = true, DropDownList is enable, else DropDownList is disabled. how to achieve it?

Comment: What is the point of this - disabled attributes do not post back their value, and why render all the options when all you need to to display the text value of the property. And what is the condition based on - another property in your model?

Comment: Is `$('#Types').removeAttr("disabled")` you're looking for in client-side? I think using `disabled` property in DDL discouraged at some cases, use display HTML helper instead.

Comment: I edit it just now, please look at it once,  I want to Dynamic setting attribute disabled with one bool value in RazorView?

Comment: Which property in model you want to use to disable or enable the dropdown?

Comment: @User3250, I want to use a bool value which is from the background to dynamic set DropDownList disabled attribute

Comment: Background means what here? From js or from model?

Comment: you can understand from model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the dropdown based on a property of your model:

```
@if(Model.DisableDropdown)
{ 
    @Html.DropDownList("OptionType", selectList, new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownList("OptionType", selectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

Comment: I want to use another way,  use disabled attribute. thank you!

Comment: @Superman why you don't want to use Adiga's answer?

Comment: I want to know whether  can only use disabled attribute to achieve it, I think use "if else" is not concise

Comment: @Superman we can't use ternary operator for "disabled", so we have to use if else. This is much simpler and readable than creating a custom html helper.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

creating an extension for HtmlHelper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionText, bool IsDisabled)
    {
        if (IsDisabled)   
            return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionText, new { @disabled = "disabled" });
        else
            return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionText);

    }
}
```

In razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Types, "", Model.IsDisabled)
```

Comment: thank you! MVC Own attributes can not resolve it ? must extension HtmlHelper?

Comment: For your requirement its helpful to you

Comment: You are great!  Your way is great!

Comment: Glad it helps :) If you find it's useful to you please marked as answer for future references as well