# Disable DropDownList with the ability to pass the value to the update model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, post

I want my `DropDownList` to show only preselected value, user shouldn't be able to change it. I was able to do it using the `disable` attribute:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.ViewBagList= new SelectList(db.Table, "Id", "Name", table.id);
```

View (Part of my POST form):

```
@Html.DropDownList("ViewBagList", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

And it works fine, I see the selected value in list. The problem is when I try to update row in database through this model:

```
 db.Entry(table).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();;
```

The problem is that when my DropDownList is `disabled` the value passed to the instance `table` is null, whereas when it isn't `disabled` it passes correct value.

How can I restrict user from changing value in DropDownList and still have the value passed to my instance?

Comment: you can try using readonly attribute instead of disabled.

Comment: DropDownList doesn't have readonly attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more digging I've found the answer on stack by user @BGStack :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27890803/11646848

I will quote him in case it's deleted:

> Regarding the catch 22:
>
> If we use @disabled, the field is not sent to the action (Mamoud) And if we use >@readonly, the drop down bug still lets you change the value
>
> Workaround: use @disabled, and add the field hidden after the drop down:
>
> ```
> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.xxxxxxxx)
> ```
>
> Then it is truly disabled, and sent to the to the action too.