# ASP.Net Core 3: How do I make an @Html.DropDownListFor "read-only" with a default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1.

I inherited some "select/option" lists that look like this:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="Q5_div">
        <label>@Questions.Q5*</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answers.Q5, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo))),
          "Select Yes or No",
           new {@class = "custom-select", @id = "Answers_Q5" })
    </div>
```

All well and good.  The user selects "Yes" or "No" from the dropdown, and the value is written to the database.

**GOAL:**

I'd like to hard code "No", and make the field read-only.  Here's what I tried:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="Q5_div">
        <label>@Questions.Q5*</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answers.Q5, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo))),
          "No",
           new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "custom-select", @id = "Answers_Q5" })
    </div>
```

**Problem**

"Answers.Q5" is always `null`. The DropDownList never gets bound to "Answers_Q5"; the model never gets the value "No".

Q: How can I make an ASP.Net Core @Html.DropDownList "read-only" with a default value?

Comment: Try to do it with `@readonly="readonly"` replacing `@disabled="disabled"`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, @readonly isn't an option for ASP.Net DropDownLists.  If I changed the above example to `@readonly="readonly"`, the dropdown defaults to "No" ... but it allows me to select either "Yes" or "No" :(  Sorry.

Comment: Then you have to do an extra work along with using `disabled`. Would you like if I put it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please.  My workarounds would include a) substitute `@Html.TextBox` (for which "readonly" *DOES* work), or b) manually add a parallel `<input type="hidden">` field for the value.  I'm curious about your thoughts.

Comment: Mine is the 2nd option of using it in hidden (along with dropdonlist including @disabled) but with MVC helper, so that the binded data available to Action method.

Comment: Write down the options in answer, would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At  Sh.Imran's request, I posted my workarounds:

**Goal:**  Make an ASP.Net Core @Html.DropDownList "read-only" with a default value.

**Challenge:** Many elements allow the "readonly" attribute; apparently DropDownList doesn't.

The scenario is described here: [how to give #readonly in DropdownListfor in asp.net MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636103/)

**Option 1:**

Make DropDownList @Disabled, add a parallel "input type=hidden" element for the binding:

```
<div class="form-group" id="Q5_div">
    <label>@Questions.Q5*</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answers.Q5, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo))),
      "No",
       new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "custom-select", @id = "Answers_Q5" })
    <input type="hidden" name="Answers.Q5" value="No"/>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

Substitute @Html.TextBox (which supports "readonly") for DropDownList:

```
<div class="form-group" id="Q5_div">
    <label>@Questions.Q5*</label>"
```

I verified both, and chose Option 2. It's less verbose, and easier to maintain.

---

Addendum:

One other alternative for "Option 1" (use "@Html.DropDownListFor()", mark "disabled" ... but still write the default value) is to put all the `<input type="hidden">` tags together, at the top of the file.

EXAMPLE:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Answers.Q5" value="No" /> 
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Answers.Q6" value="Yes" /> 
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Answers.Q7" value="Maybe" />
```

This can simplify code maintenance, but it still ensures all the default values are written to the database.